# WPF Bing Maps With REST: Cant figure out how to add routes

Tags: c#, wpf, rest, routes, bing

There's a lot of tutorials in the web talking about the WinRT bing maps for Store Apps. This is what I want to do with WPF:

https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/geocoding-and-routing-in-bing-maps-windows-store-apps-native/

I was translating this tutorial to WPF. However, in the WPF bing maps there's none MapShapeLayer, for example, making this impossible to follow.

How to implement this using the WPF Bing controls?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have never added items to the map programmatically but I believe you simply add them to the maps `Children` property.  I try to stick with the MVVM pattern so I rely on bindings and the underlying viewmodel to update the map accordingly.  Here is a sample of XAML from one of my projects - I think it will get you going in the right direction:

```
  <bingControl:Map x:Name="DirectionsMap"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   AnimationLevel="Full"
                   Background="{StaticResource MapBackgroundBrush}"
                   CredentialsProvider="<YourCredentialsHere>"
                   ScaleVisibility="Collapsed"
                   ZoomLevel="5">
     <bingControl:Pushpin x:Name="StartPushin"
                          Width="Auto"
                          Height="Auto"
                          Panel.ZIndex="50"
                          Content="{Binding StartAddress.Name}"
                          Location="{Binding StartAddress.Location}"
                          Style="{StaticResource DirectionsEndpointPushpinStyle}" />
     <bingControl:Pushpin x:Name="DestinationPushpin"
                          Width="Auto"
                          Height="Auto"
                          Panel.ZIndex="50"
                          Content="{Binding DestinationAddress.Name}"
                          Location="{Binding DestinationAddress.Location}"
                          Style="{StaticResource DirectionsEndpointPushpinStyle}" />
     <bingControl:MapItemsControl x:Name="DirectionsEdges"
                                  Panel.ZIndex="10"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding DirectionsResult.RoutePath}">
        <bingControl:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
              <bingControl:MapPolyline Panel.ZIndex="20"
                                       Locations="{Binding ''}"
                                       Stroke="#5968F7"
                                       StrokeThickness="4" />
           </DataTemplate>
        </bingControl:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </bingControl:MapItemsControl>
  </bingControl:Map>
```